# how to have each option in a drop down list call a different function when submit is selected?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form with 5 option values (test, test1, test2, test3, test4).  When the user selects the submit button for either one, I need for it to call a different function (function test1(), function test2(), etc....)

using some php I need for these functions to be called on submit.

I am trying something like   if (isset(_POST['test1']) && (isset(_POST['submit'] {
test1();
} else if ...

I cant seem to get this to call the function.  Maybe I have the value wrong for each option.  I just have the values - value="test" value="test1" and so on.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated..Thanks

Comment: show the HTML of your form please

Comment: im sorry i dont hsve it with me.  the form is simple...each option has a value and name and are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a name to the selector:

```
<select name="selector">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>
</select>
```

Then check the value of the selector

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['selector']) && 'test' == $_POST['selector']) { 
    test(); 
} 
else if (isset($_POST['selector']) && 'test1' == $_POST['selector']) { 
    test1(); 
}
```